# Azure Graph API Reporting Schema

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

For the live of me I cannot find documentation on the Azure AD Graph API reporting API schema for the SSPR reports that are returned as JSON data.

Two specific examples:

**Example 1: The SSPR Registration Activity Report**

https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/reports/ssprRegistrationActivityEvents?api-version=beta

This API response includes a JSON attribute called "registrationActivity" with values such as reportSSPR_RegistrationData_LastRegisteredTime, reportSSPR_RegistrationData_PrivateAlternateEmail, reportSSPR_RegistrationData_PrivateMobilePhone.

**Example 2: The SSPR Activity Report**

https://graph.windows.net/kforce.onmicrosoft.com/reports/ssprRegistrationActivityEvents?api-version=beta

This API response includes a JSON attribute called "result" with values such as reportSSPR_ResultType_Failed, reportSSPR_ResultType_Block, and reportSSPR_ResultType_Succeeded.

I need to know the possible values that can be returned but this information has eluded me thus far.

Can anyone point me to the schema documentation for these API responses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the metadata for the Azure ad reporting API via links below:

Activities metadata:

https://graph.windows.net/tenant-name/activities/$metadata?api-version=beta

Reports metadata:

https://graph.windows.net/tenant-name/reports/$metadata?api-version=beta

And the request for `https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/reports/ssprRegistrationActivityEvents?api-version=beta` returns the type of `ssprRegistrationActivityEvents`. You can check it through reports metadata like below:

```
<EntityType Name="SsprRegistrationActivityEvent">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="id" />
</Key>
<Property Name="eventTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="role" Type="Edm.String" />
<Property Name="registrationActivity" Type="Edm.String" />
<Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String" />
<Property Name="userName" Type="Edm.String" />
</EntityType>
```